# Why is my SD card not being recognized?

Tags: lxde, sd-card

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 on a VAIO notebook. Here is my `uname` output:

```
Linux vaio 3.0.0-16-generic-pae #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 19:24:01 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know why but today my SD card is not working. When I plug it nothing happens.

I tried some hints from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15385/19195) but nothing. I don't have any `sdf` on `/dev` folder.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Where did my card go?

**ps:**  here is my unity utilities window, suggesting me to try `sdb`

[image]

Comment: Can you see data on the disk from another machine?  If not, your card might be corrupt.  More information will pop up on /var/log/dmesg (look at the last 30 lines or so just after you insert the card.)

Comment: I can use it on my sony camera.

Comment: I found: `[   16.620316] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   16.620440] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   16.620476] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   16.620591] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   16.376381] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC           1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[   16.376421] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic- MemoryStick      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
`

Answer (score 1):

The card got renamed from sdf to sdb. There could be a multitude of reasons. Does it work as you expect? How do you mount it?

Comment: I can not mount it. The last time I just inserted and a window appears. But today, nothing happens.

Comment: I'd suggest a reboot in that case. If that doesn't solve the issue, what does ls /dev/sd* say?

Comment: `/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdc`

Comment: I've just reboot. I don't know why but I inserted and nothing. Then, I removed it and inserted again. Now it works!

Comment: You can find out what mount point it is currently using, now, by typing 'mount' in a terminal.  Keep in mind, that mount point may change as you use other removable storage devices.

Comment: Thanks. I found `/dev/sdb1 on /media/disk type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)`

Comment: @Stephan, where is the information that the mount point is `/media/disk`. I didn't find it on `fstab`.

Comment: This is most likely a dynamic mount done by a daemon in your system.  Thus it would not appear in the /etc/fstab.